# Search with Regex

Tags: qt

I want to search all qDebug() throughout my project but not the commented qDebug() , that is //qDebug() or /* qDebug() */. In QtCreator Edit >Find/Replace>Advanced Search option is giving an option "Use regular expression" and I think I have to use it to achieve what I want. But I can't form the Regex expression. Can anyone help ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your syntax is, but you can try something like this:

```
^[^\/]*qDebug\(\)$
```

it excludes every `/` character preceding `qDebug()`. It's not perfect, because it exclude, for example, `a=b/2; qDebug();`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't put the $ at the end or qDebug() << "text"; won't match